# Iterator with shared pointer gives unexpected results

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having trouble implementing `operator++`.

When I run it it prints the first element correctly but then prints wrong characters.

```
class iterator
{
public:
    iterator(shared_ptr<T> ptr) : ptr_(ptr) { }

    iterator(T* ptr)  {
        shared_ptr<T> temp = shared_ptr<T>(ptr);
        ptr_ = temp;
    }

    ~iterator(){
        ptr_ = nullptr;
    }

    iterator operator++() {


        ptr_ = shared_ptr<T>(ptr_.get()+1);

        return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int) {
          iterator i = ptr_;
        ptr_ = shared_ptr<T>(ptr_.get()+1);

        return i;
    }
    T& operator*() { return *(ptr_.get()); }

private:
    shared_ptr<T> ptr_;
};
```

Comment: You cannot create a `shared_ptr` to an existing object unless you are taking sole ownership of it in doing so. Since I'm assuming `ptr_` points to an element in an array (or `ptr_.get()+1` wouldn't make sense) then that array already has ownership of the pointed objects. You would need to provide a do-nothing custom deleter, but then what's the point of using a `shared_ptr`? This design looks extremely broken and I'm not sure where one would begin fixing it.

Comment: Only ever construct smart pointers with a pointer returned by `new`.  `ptr_.get() + 1` is not a pointer returned by `new`, so you should never construct a smart pointer using that pointer.

Comment: I use default deleter and yes I have array @FrançoisAndrieux how access next element of my array ?

Comment: @johnny003 I don't see why your iterator needs ownership of the container's elements. Just use `T* ptr_;`.

Comment: can't I use shared ? @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @johnny003 Maybe, but it's going to be extremely complicated for little to no gain, and even some loss of performance. It's not clear to me that you understand the problem. You cannot simply take a raw pointer to an existing pointer and stick it in a `shared_ptr` unless you know nothing else will destroy the pointed object. Otherwise, your `shared_ptr` will eventually destroy that pointed object, but so will whatever else already owned it.

Comment: how can I use new ?@MilesBudnek

Comment: @johnny003 If you're not using `new` (or `make_shared`) you do not need `shared_ptr`.  The point of smart pointers is to make sure objects that got created with `new` (or `new[]`) get destroyed with `delete` (or `delete[]`) (or sometimes other things that need manual cleanup).  If you're just using an automatic array then you don't need `shared_ptr` at all.

Comment: Also `iterator(T* ptr)` should be removed. It is not a good practice to move ownership using raw pointer as it is not obvious from the calling code that it will happen.

Comment: If it is an array, then you should probably use `shared_ptr<T[]>` instead. And another problem with this design is that the size is lost so `iterator` cannot do any validation. This is bad as it make it harder to find bugs and improper usages. Why not use `std::vector`?